# Javascript optimisation Event Listener for multiple time the same effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want something that when I have a addEventListener('mouseover') it affect the two element next to him.

Like this:

```js
let three = document.getElementById('three');
let six = document.getElementById('six');

intersection3_6.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
  three.classList.add("hover");
  six.classList.add("hover");
});
intersection3_6.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
  three.classList.remove("hover");
  six.classList.remove("hover");
});
```

```css
#table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 50px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px;
}

#controls {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 44px 12px 44px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#intersection3_6 {
  pointer-events: all;
  background-color: red;
  grid-column-start: 2;
}


.hover {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <button id="three"><span>3</span></button>
  <button id="six"><span>6</span></button>
  <div id='controls'>
    <div class='vertical' id='intersection3_6'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It work but obviously when I have something like this with multiple intersections it's getting boring and not optimised to repeat myself everytime (we can just concentrate on  the first row where the purple intersections are)
[image]

Is there a way to say something like 'take the one on your left and the one on your right and do the thing' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over all the elements with the same class, and use DOM navigation operations to reach the elements next to the event target.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".vertical").forEach(int => {
    int.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
        let table = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
        table.childElements[0].classList.add('hover');
        table.childElements[1].classList.add('hover');
    });
    int.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
        let table = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
        table.childElements[0].classList.remove('hover');
        table.childElements[1].classList.remove('hover');
    });
});
```